# CodeIgniter - Private Functions Access?

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, frameworks

When we make a function private in controller then it cannot be accessed by URL in browser.
I read documentation and nothing more, even can't find about it on the internet.

The question is.
private function cannot be accessed by URL, directly.
So how we can access them?
How to get to them?
How use private functions...?

Comment: A private function has class wide scope. You can call the function from within other functions in the class where the private function resides or from anywhere else within that class.

Comment: What is the reason of using function of the same class inside other function? How does it help us? What are good situations to use it?

Comment: @AdriannoBarello - read tereško's advice before trying anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the function by using `$this` inside the controller.

```
class T1 extends CI_Controller{

 public function fun1()
 {
  echo $this->fun2(5,6);
 }
 private function fun2($x,$y)
 {
   return $x+$y;
 }
}

Output: 
URL: http://localhost/myproject/t1/fun1
11
```

Comment: Why using function inside controller used by other function in the same controller? This kind of function (fun2) shouldn't be inside Model? Especially when this kind of calc (x+y) can be done in fun1 even without Model.

Comment: @AdriannoBarello this is just an example, no link with the real-time situation.

Comment: Okay, but What can be real-time situation to use this method? When is it confortable / recommended to use, mmmm....

Answer (score 0):

Its a good question,you are correct if the method is not accessible why do you want a method, if it is accessible why do you need to define it private.
This has nothing to do with your php knowledge.

These methods can be called from another method inside the same class, a practical usage can be you can call this after checking the session variables in another method,for an  example the method is called only when the user is logged in. It would provide code simplicity in the calling method.
and if you dont make it private user may directly access it without logging in